# How to implement dynamic array/list in apex like vector in c++

Tags: apex, trigger

If we want to concatenate current collection elements to same collection ex: if current collection contains {1,2,3} how to write logic in apex to make its value {1,2,3,1,2,3} without using any extra collection. Below is the implementation of similar logic in c++ using vector. Can we use list/map collections as an alternative to vector?

```
 vector<int> getConcatenation(vector<int>& nums) {
    int listSize = nums.size();
    for(int i=0;i<listSize;i++)
    {
        nums.push_back(nums[i]);
    }
    return nums;
    }
```

Tried similar logic (below) in apex using list but got : List index out of bound error

```
public static List<Integer> concatenationOfArray(List<Integer>originalIntegerArray)
{
    Integer listSize = originalIntegerArray.size();
    for(Integer i=0;i<listSize;i++)
    {
        originalIntegerArray[listSize+i] = originalIntegerArray[i];
    }
    return originalIntegerArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `[1, 2, 3]` and want to end up with `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`, then the simplest approach would be to use `.addAll()` and pass the current list.

```
List<Integer> myList = new List<Integer>{1, 2, 3};
myList.addAll(myList);
system.debug(myList); // prints (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The more literal translation of your code in Apex would be to use the `List.add` method:

```
Integer[] myList = new Intger[] { 1, 2, 3 };
for(Integer index = 0, size = myList.size(); index < size; index++) {
  myList.add(myList[index]);
}
```

Where `add` behaves identically to `push_back`, though the underlying implementation is likely different.

In your specific case, I would still recommend using `addAll`, as given by Derek, for performance reasons. However, I wanted to bring this to your attention in case you have need for it in the future.